# Windows Phone 8.1 - Add text to Image

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8.1

I've been struggling with this for a day now and it's really frustrating because it is something that you would expect to be so simple, yet, there's a lot of questions regarding this on the net.

How do you add text to a image in a Windows Phone 8.1 Project.

What I've seen thus far is create a WriteableBitmap, some examples using the constructor which takes a BitmapImage.  Well, the only constructor I have take a width and height.

Then you can add a textblock to the writeableBitmap using .Render(UIElement, …  Well, I don't have a .Render method on the WriteableBitmap instance.

I'm also using the WriteableBitmapEx library as well.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Ccommunity edition and it is a Windows Phone 8.1 project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example how to render an arbitrary UI element named **uielement** to a bitmap and then copying it to a WriteableBitmap:

```
  var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
  await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(uielement);
  var buf = await renderBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
  bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(renderBitmap.PixelWidth, renderBitmap.PixelHeight);
  using (var stream1 = buf.AsStream())
  using (var stream2 = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
  {
    await stream1.CopyToAsync(stream2);
  }
```